# Differentiating background-color based on browser support of CSS properties

Tags: css, progressive-enhancement

I have created a polka dotted background in pure CSS via:

```css
.polka-gr{
    
    background-image:radial-gradient(#FAFFB3 20%, transparent 0), radial-gradient(#F1C3CB 20%, transparent 0);
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: 0 0, 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="polka-gr" style="background-color:#77FFD1;width:600px;height:200px;></div>
```

As you can see, the background color is a greenish shade (of hex value `#77FFD1`).

Some of the clients this code is being served to do not support `radial-gradient` (e.g. those using Opera Mini browser). All such clients currently fall back to a plain `#77FFD1` background without polka dots. Fair enough.

But is there any pure CSS way to get these non-supporting browsers to fall back to a *different color entirely*, e.g. `#FFFF99`?

Supporting browsers should still see the greenish background-color (`#77FFD1`) with polka dots.

Is such an arrangement possible? If so, an illustrative example would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.polka-gr{
  background: yellow;
}

@supports (background: radial-gradient(#F1C3CB 20%, transparent 0)) {
.polka-gr{

    background-image:radial-gradient(#FAFFB3 20%, transparent 0), radial-gradient(#F1C3CB 20%, transparent 0);
      background-color:#77FFD1;
      background-size: 30px 30px;
      background-position: 0 0, 15px 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="polka-gr" style="width:600px;height:200px;></div>
```

To target different browsers you can use `@supports`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40supports

In your case:

```
@supports (background: radial-gradient(white, black)) {
  /* relevant styles here */
}
```

Comment: As in, I set the background color to the fallback value I need, and then place the code for advanced browsers within the snippet you've shown? Would be better to see a slight bit more detail here.

Comment: If it doesn't support radial-gradient, I question whether it supports @supports

Comment: @Rob: I see that `@support` has good support beyond IE: https://caniuse.com/#search=%40supports And IE isn't really my use case. But if you have an alternative suggestion, I'd like to look into that as well.

Comment: It appears feature queries are supported in all browsers save *IE* (the only exception again). Ref: https://caniuse.com/#search=%40supports & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40supports#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Added the snippet. `@support` has pretty good support except IE.

Comment: @Kushtrim: thanks for the elaboration. But maybe it's just me; I still can't see how that snippet falls back to a different color (e.g. `#FFFF99`)? Could you explain a bit? Like where's the actual fallback happening?

Comment: @HassanBaig If I do understand you correctly, you need a background without "dots" when there is no support for radial-gradient. In that case you have a default value of _background: #77FFD1_ . If browsers supports _radial-gradient_ then proceed to show background with "dots".

Comment: @Kushtrim: no I already had that part covered. What I require is this: I want a **green** background with polka dots for supported devices. I want a plain **yellow** background for unsupported devices. I.e. not only the polka dots disappear, but the BG color's different too.

Comment: @Kushtrim Yes but his problem is related to old browsers, not current ones.

Comment: @HassanBaig I think you can add default value of `background: yellow` and if browser supports `radial-gradient` then polka background will show. Updated the snippet.

Comment: Yep, that's what I needed. It works. Thanks a lot :-)